# How to disable yellow lines around elements in the website while opening the google dev console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

A while ago, when I turned on the google dev console, yellow lines around elements started appearing. I don't know what option I turned on by mistake but even after resetting to default, the problem still persists. Is this a new feature and how can I disable it?

[image: annoying lines]

Can someone help me turn it off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably the React Developer Tools. Disable the `Highlight updates when components render` option. I accidentally turned it on recently and faced the same problem.

It is off by default.

[image]